# Cannot Download PDF's Using Selenium/Python 3.x, But It works When I do it Manually

Tags: pdf, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, geckodriver, pypdf

I read through a ton of answers to this query of mine but couldn't find anything specific. Hence asking here

Here's the scenario, On a webpage, when I click a download button, it downloads a PDF file correctly, On the browser, I have set the Firefox preferences to save the file rather than open in preview.

However, when I run my selenium/Python script, the download keeps opening in the preview, there are other PDF downloads on the page and they work fine. Upon inspecting both the download buttons, the only difference I see is the one that does not download has a relative URL in its href value.

I am also using the following firefox options settings in my script, but with no help. Please guide me in the right direction. Thanks in advance!

## **************************

```
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.dir", 'Path to Save The file')
fp.set_preference("pdfjs.enabledCache.state", False)
fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/pdf")
fp.set_preference("pdfjs.disabled", "true")

# disable Adobe Acrobat PDF preview plugin
fp.set_preference("plugin.scan.plid.all", "false")
fp.set_preference("plugin.scan.Acrobat", "99.0")
self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp,executable_path="path to my geckodriver")
self.driver.get("url")
```

Comment: try adding 'application/octet-stream' to 'neverAsk.saveToDisk and this two options "browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", false
              "browser.download.manager.useWindow", false

Comment: Thanks, @Infern0 - still the same, adding those options didn't help either

Comment: can you confirm if the file has been downloaded in the provided folder, also set the  geckodriver for linux /usr/bin for windows in env path and try again without adding executable_path to firefox class

Comment: No file downloaded thus far, I moved the geckodriver to /usr/bin on my Mac, updated the geckodriver path to /usr/bin in the script and ran it again - still no downloads :-(

Comment: Folks, is anyone else having this problem? Please advise

Comment: Strangely, other PDF's work just fine, its just a couple of them that are problematic and I am unable to find a solution. The first one downloads but the tool cannot open the file - throws the following exception "../../../../../venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyPDF2/pdf.py:1689: OSError", the second one does not download at all...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem - setting to disable pdfjs only worked when clicked manually on about:config page. Turned out that what seems to have solved the issue was (Firefox 60.6.1ESR):

```
profile.setPreference("pdfjs.disabled", true);
profile.setPreference("pdfjs.enabledCache.state", false); // <= THIS
```